# iPhone app has a "Shopping Cart" -How to convert custom objects into XML to be sent to the server

Tags: iphone, serialization, plist

I have a shopping cart in my iPhone app. Once the user is done with his shopping, I would like to send the contents of  the cart to a server where a PHP script processes the input.

After researching online, I saw that I could convert all the contents into an XML file and send that for processing to the server.

Then I tried to find how to do that in Apple's documentation. Here I found that I can only convert data structures that are arrays, strings, numbers, bools and dictionaries into XML files or pLists.
But I have custom objects and arrays both in my cart. I want to convert to XML.

So I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions or links to sample code that I could use to accomplish this task.

Here is how my cart's init method looks:

```
-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (sharedSingleton != nil ) 
   {
    NSLog(@"inside init for Cart");
    totalItemsInCart = 0;
    self.foodItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0]; 
    self.drinkItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];       
    self.otherItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0]; 
    selectedLocation = nil; //location object
    locationSelected = FALSE; //bool
    customerInfo = nil; //customer info model
    customerInfoObtained = FALSE; //bool
    self.numFoodItems = 0; //int
    self.gratuity = 0; //float
    self.miscCharges = 0; //float
    [self calculateTaxPercents];
   }

return sharedSingleton;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "call a method" way to do this.
the way to go is to find an xml library that can create and edit xml. 
A quick search reveals [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/)

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't my question. Im not looking to parse an XML. Im looking to create one. I found the answer on Apples documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH5-SW1